# Spot the memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

simply put, my sqlservr.exe is memory leaking when ever my service uses it. So the question is, Where and why! :(

I intialise my connection as nulls. and have a finally clause to ensure they are closed... (ive also tried .dispose on the datareader, but doesnt help).

I've tried identifying the problem for over a day. All I can tell is that it is here somewhere.

```
private Int32 GetCount(String From, String Where)
{

    //Build SQL string from given parameters.
    String sql = "SET dateformat DMY SELECT COUNT(*) as Count FROM " + From + " WHERE " + Where;
    SqlDataReader dataCount = null;
    SqlCommand sqlCommCount = null;
    SqlConnection sqlConCount = null;
    try
    {
        sqlCommCount = new SqlCommand();
        sqlConCount = new SqlConnection();
        sqlCommCount.Connection = sqlConCount;
        sqlConCount.ConnectionString = "connectionstring";
        sqlCommCount.CommandText = sql;
        sqlConCount.Open();

        dataCount = sqlCommCount.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataCount.Read())
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(dataCount["Count"]);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConCount.Close();
        sqlCommCount.Dispose();
        if (dataCount != null)
            dataCount.Close();

    }
}
```

**SOLVED:**

1. There is no leak.
2. I hate Sqlserver for not telling me it caches memory that isnt in use when connections are madee, so just increases and increases (until it is needed).

Comment: If your _server_ is really leaking then we won't find it in this piece of _client_ code.

Comment: Sorry for being too lazy to give a proper answer but 'Using' blocks are a way better way to handle IDisposables than the try/catch/finally thing you've got going on there.

Comment: In the code above, you are not disposing your SqlDataReader and I don't think your connection is getting disposed either.  As some of the other answers indicated, you should use the 'using' keyword so that objects are automatically disposed.  Also, how do you know you have a memory leak?  How did you determine this?

Comment: using resource manager, it is just going up and up. Sqlservr is the database. This is my webservice code, connecting to the database. Something is not being closed, or something, causing the memory on the sqlservr.exe to go up (and never down). Ill try the using, it sounds like a better idea.

Comment: @Doomsknight: In its configuration, what amount of memory is SQL Server allowed to use? Does it stop increasing at that limit? Are you benchmarking this method by doing the very same `from` and `where` for each call?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: He is closing everything just fine. All the `Dispose()` methods do is call `Close()`, and closing them should be enough since we're regarding the service's memory footprint rather than the client.

Comment: @Joel - I didn't notice the close call on the DataReader in the finally block.

Comment: @Joel. Yes I am looping the same call 1000 times, and then executing it every so often. Changed to using, and still no sucess. Found an example code that uses, using for datareaders on msdn. Is it possible that the sqlserver is actually leaking byitself? Surely not? :@ I dont know what to. Are you suggesting that it will increase a certain amount as like a cache or something? and then use the unused memory? So nothing is actually leaking?

Comment: @Doomsknight: It's normal for a database server to secure a very large amount of memory. The best possible performance of a database is when it can fit everything in memory so that it does only as much disk reading/writing as is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your code with this keyword: **using**

Memory occupation is not deterministic, in you sample the effective memory used by the executable will be freed only when Garbage Collection occurs, so you can see memory increase but this could be not an issue, it will be collected sooner or later and memory will return to a proper value.

After seeing the comment, then the problem seems not to be in your C# code (also if using the using keyword it's a good idea!), if there is a problem...

SQL Server will increase memory occupation until it has memory available, it's designed to work that way. In your sample each time you pass a new where clause it will cache the SQL statement and so memory usage will increase until you have memory available.

In this case I suggest you to refactor your code to use at least SQL parameters to create the where clause, so the SQL will always remains the same and only the parameters change, this way SQL server will cache only one SQL statement and not thousands. Better yet is to create a stored procedure, but parameters are usually enough.

Keep also in mind that the way you're building your SQL statement is really unsafe and could lead to SQL injection attacks, using parameters will fix that too.

Regards

Massimo

Comment: using resource manager, sqlservr.exe is going up and up. Ive had it on now a while, and at no point has it gone down. When this webservice starts being called 100s of times.. to 1000s, with no server restart then it will run out of memory.

Comment: The string "where" is built from passed in parameters, this is just a method I made to reuse. preventing code repetition. I have applied some sort of sql injection prevention on my string parameters. It will hopefully be QA'd by another member of my team to ensure I have done it correctly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

your Conenction *sqlConCount* is never really disposed.

the Dispose implementation of SqlConnection closes the connection before disposing. so the best would be to use a using command for the connection and you can be sure that the problem wont lie there.

but as you dont save a reference it should be anyway garbage collected, so not really a problem. are you 100% sure the memory leak is in here?

Comment: Pretty sure. I call this method up (not running any other code at all!) and my sqlservr.exe goes up and up and up and up till i start crying :(.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're returning your integer before finally block has a chance to fire. Try assigning it in try block and return it after the finally block

```
int value = o;
try
{
  ... 
  value = Convert.ToInt32(dataCount["Count"]);
}
finally
{
//close connection
}
return value;
```

Comment: finally will be called in any way, even you end the method with a return

Comment: Aye, it executes anyway. I did check just to make sure this wasnt the problem :)

Answer (score -2):

i think `string + string` causes leaking, swtich to StringBuilder. also you're not disposing `SqlConCount` and `dataCount` (you could try to refactor your code using `using`

Comment: "string + string" does not cause a memory leak. There would be no gain in this example by using a StringBuilder.

Comment: everybody knows that concatenation allocates a new object and copies data to it

Comment: That is true.  That is NOT a memory leak.